Plotly サブプロット付きのグラフについて
下記コードを実行するると添付図のようなグラフになります。この画像のオレンジ色の箇所を表示させたくないのですが可能ですか？

import datetime
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

class KabuGraph:
    def __init__(self, ticker, date_from):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.date_from = date_from

    def get_data(self):
        print(f"ティッカー: {self.ticker}")
        print(f"開始日: {self.date_from}")
        hist = yf.Ticker(self.ticker).history(
            start=self.date_from,
            end=datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        )
        hist = hist.round(2)
        hist.index = hist.index.date
        hist = hist.sort_index(ascending=False)
        hist.rename(columns={
            "Open" : "始値",
            "High" : "高値",
            "Low" : "安値",
            "Close" : "終値",
            "Volume" : "出来高",
            "Dividends" : "配当",
            "Stock Splits" : "株式分割",
            }, inplace=True)
        hist.reset_index(inplace=True)
        hist.rename(columns={"index" : "日付"}, inplace=True)
        hist["日付"] = pd.to_datetime(hist["日付"]) # queryをつかうのでto_datetimeを使う
        return hist

    def data_period(self, hist, begin=datetime.date(2024,1,1), end=None):
        if end is None:
            end = datetime.date.today()

        begin_str = pd.Timestamp(begin).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        end_str = pd.Timestamp(end).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


        # df_period = hist[(hist["日付"] >= begin) & (hist["日付"] <= end)]
        # Using query method
        query_string = f"日付 >= '{begin}' and 日付 <= '{end}'"
        df_period = hist.query(query_string)
        return df_period

    def line_graph(self, hist):
        fig = px.line(hist, x="日付", y="終値", title="SoftBank株価推移")
        fig.show()

    def candlestick_graph(self, hist):
        # サブプロット付きのグラフを作成
        fig = make_subplots(rows = 2, cols = 1, shared_xaxes=True,
                            vertical_spacing = 0.03, subplot_titles=("キャンドルスティック","出来高"),
                            row_width = [0.2, 0.3]
        )

        # キャンドルスティックチャートを追加
        fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(
            x = hist["日付"],
            open = hist["始値"],
            high = hist["高値"],
            low = hist["安値"],
            close = hist["終値"],
            increasing_line_color="red",
            decreasing_line_color="green"
        ), row = 1, col = 1)

        # 出来高の棒グラフを追加
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x = hist["日付"],
            y = hist["出来高"],
            marker_color = "blue"
        ), row = 2, col = 1)

        fig.update_layout(
                title="SoftBank株価ロウソク足チャート",
                # xaxis_title = "日付",
                yaxis_title = "株価",
                # xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False
                showlegend = False
         )
        # fig.update_xaxes(title_text="日付", row=1, col=1)  # 上段のプロット（キャンドルスティックチャート）の日付軸
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="株価", row=1, col=1)  # 上段のプロット（キャンドルスティックチャート）の株価軸

        fig.update_xaxes(title_text="日付", row=2, col=1)  # 下段のプロット（出来高チャート）の日付軸
        fig.update_yaxes(title_text="出来高", row=2, col=1)  # 下段のプロット（出来高チャート）の出来高軸

        fig.show()


def main():
    date_from = "2020-01-01"
    kabu_graph = KabuGraph("9434.T", date_from)
    hist = kabu_graph.get_data()
    hist = kabu_graph.data_period(hist)
    # kabu_graph.line_graph(hist)
    kabu_graph.candlestick_graph(hist)
    print(hist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


ソースコード表示領域の訂正ありがとうございます。
はじめてでどう変更していいかわかりませんでした。
ありがとうございます。

この記事がちょうど当てはまるでしょう。
Python で日本の株価を取得し、インタラクティブなロウソク足チャートを作成する
上記の「チャート成形（営業日のみ・移動平均線）」として表示・説明されているソースコードの中でサラッと「# 期間スライダーを非表示」として指定されているものですね。
対象処理だけを抽出すれば以下になります。
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible=False)

def candlestick_graph(self, hist):のfig.show()の前に挿入しておけば良いですね。
そして上記記事に記載された複数のソースコードの組み合わせで「週末祝日を非表示」の処理を実現しているようなので、それらも参考になるでしょう。

教えてくださった方法で期間スライダーを非表示にすることができました。
ありがとうございます。
